# Docker alpine: ffprobe not found, despite installing ffmpeg with apk in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, ffmpeg, alpine-linux

I have a Go program that executes `ffmpeg` and `ffprobe` commands, so I need to install them in my Docker container.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.17.7-alpine

WORKDIR /src
COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download
COPY . .
RUN go build -o ./server cmd/service/main.go

RUN apk update
RUN apk upgrade
RUN apk add --no-cache ffmpeg

FROM alpine
COPY --from=0 /src/server /usr/bin/server
CMD ["server"]
```

However, when I run container, it says:

```
exec: "ffprobe": executable file not found in $PATH
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because ffmpeg is a runtime dependency, not a build tool, you have to add it in the `FROM alpine` section, not the `FROM golang:1.17.7-alpine` section, such that it's installed on the image that your server is actually run in, not the system image that your server is compiled against.

The smallest change to your original code that makes it work, then, would just consist of moving lines around, without needing to change anything further:

```
FROM golang:1.17.7-alpine
WORKDIR /src
COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download
COPY . .
RUN go build -o ./server cmd/service/main.go

FROM alpine
RUN apk update
RUN apk upgrade
RUN apk add --no-cache ffmpeg
COPY --from=0 /src/server /usr/bin/server
CMD ["server"]
```

Comment: now, I get an error like no such file or directory: test.mp4. It is located in root path of project. How can I include it?

Comment: You should probably use a bind mount to share the directory with your data files with your service. See https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/

Comment: but why COPY . .  does not work?

Comment: You do that `COPY` in the build image, not the runtime image, so the file is no longer there at runtime.

Comment: And COPYing a big file into your Docker image is a bad idea in the first place, _especially_ if that file is going to be different run-to-run. That's going to eat up your disk space very quickly, and layer filesystems also have performance costs.

Comment: @HarunSasmaz, honestly, if you expect the `COPY . .` to still be there at runtime, maybe don't use `FROM alpine` at all and just run the server in your build image? If you don't _want_ to separate your build and runtime environments, nothing forces you to do that; and if you're willing to distribute a .mp4 file to your servers, then you clearly aren't trying to keep the runtime image as small as possible. Keeping it small is something your ops staff will thank you for, but again, it's not obligatory (except to the extent that you want to keep them happy).

Comment: (But if data is going to change or be added or provided at runtime, then you _definitely_ want to use a bind mount or volume; COPY is only for things that are going to stay the same for the life of the container)

Answer (score 0):

Just refactor you Dockerfile as bellow:

```
FROM golang:1.17.7-alpine AS builder

WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
RUN go mod tidy

RUN go build -o ./server cmd/service/main.go

FROM alpine
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache ffmpeg
COPY --from=builder /src/server /usr/bin/server
CMD ["server"]
```

Comment: Think I beat you to this by... about 13 seconds. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy :))